# Calculating reflex and obtuse angles

Tags: math, lua

Given two lines of common origin point, whose rotational angles I have in degrees, what's the best way in Lua to calculate the reflex and obtuse angles involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want the reflex angle that complements the obtuse angle, and don't worry about getting values of 90 or 180 degrees for the obtuse value:

```
function obtuse_reflex(a, b)
  local diff = (a - b) % 180
  if diff < 90 then diff = 180 - diff end
  return diff, 360 - diff
end
```

Comment: Thanks - I was starting to wonder about vectors which would have been overcomplicating it.